# SwiftUI выбор новичка?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, swiftui

Будущее за SwiftUI и с этим не поспорить, но сейчас на дворе март 2021 и я не могу определиться то ли изучать UIKit, то ли углубляться в SwiftUI. Конечно с UIKit не очень хочется связываться, понимая, что рано или поздно он перестанет быть актуальным.

Отсюда вопрос людям опытным: что сейчас изучать, как долго UIKit еще будет актуален, насколько реально найти работу зная только SwiftUI. И вообще какие настроения по этому вопросу среди проф. разработчиков?

Поделитесь пожалуйста информацией. Спасибо!

Comment: Выбрать Flutter?

Comment: По моим ощущениям и тому, что я вижу на сайтах типа hh, знание одного флатера недостаточно чтобы найти работу. Его больше представляют как дополнение к другим навыкам... Во всяком случае мне так показалось...

Comment: HR скопировала 4 вакансии в одну и опубликовала со словами «Это фуллстек, детка». Думаю тут как раз подойдёт это. По Flutter сейчас для разработки обычного приложения (не библиотеки, не приложения с какой-то вундервафлей, что и нативно мало кто напишет, ну и небольшого круга задач) достаточно понимать как открыть андроид/iOS проект и по инструкции к библиотеке прописать нужное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ситуация похожа на внедрение Swift во времена Objective-C. Вначале были только отдельные экраны на Swift, потом 50 на 50, а затем всё больше стало приложений, написанных полностью на Swift. Т.е. до полноценного перехода на SwiftUI скорее всего еще 2-3 года. Кроме того, большинство приложений до сих пор поддерживают 10-11-12 iOS, а значит, учить UIKit нужно. Полностью на SwiftUI пишутся, в основном, новые приложения.